# Django: show the sum of related Items in a template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to get the sum of all values from items related to a certain object. In concrete, I have invoices with one or many items. Each item has a price and I want to calculate the sum of the prices for all the items of one invoice.

These are the essential parts of my **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum

class Invoice(models.Model):

    @property
    def price(self): 
        return self.item_set.aggregate(Sum('price'))

class Item(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

The **view.py** is simple:

```
class InvoiceDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Invoice
```

In my template `invoice_detail.html`, `{{ invoice.price }}` delivers something like

```
{'price__sum': Decimal('282.400000000000')}
```

So I added `get('price__sum')` to the price property of the Invoice Model like that:

```
   return self.item_set.aggregate(Sum('price')).get('price__sum')
```

The result actually is fine now, i.e. the template shows something like `282.400000000000` (which I still could style a bit), but I wonder, if **that's the way to do something like that or if there is a *better* way?**

Answer (score 2):

It is better to work with [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) since then you aggregate in the *same* query. This is actually a lot better in a `ListView`: if you would use a property in a `ListView`, this will result in an *N+1* problem where you make *one* query to fetch the `Invoice`s, and *n* extra queries to obtain the price for *each* `Invoice`.

You thus can thus annotate in the view:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

class InvoiceDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Invoice
    queryset = Invoice.objects.annotate(
        price_=Coalesce(Sum('item__price'), Value(0))
    )
```

The [**`Coalesce`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) is necessary to prevent returning `NULL`/`None` in case there are *no* related items.

then in the view you can again use `{{ invoice.price_ }}`. We can not use `price`, since there is already a property for this.

You can however let annotate and the property work together with:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    # …

    @property
    def price(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'price_'):
            return self.price_
        return self.item_set.aggregate(
            price=Coalesce(Sum('price'), Value(0))
        )['price']
```

Here we thus first look if there is a `.price_` attribute, and if there is, we will not make an extra query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I will try that. One question beforehand: the "s" in `hasattr(s, 'price_')` must be "self", thus `hasattr(self, 'price_')`, right?

Comment: @RalfZosel: yes, that was a typo. Fixed, thanks!

Comment: Very good, thank you! Just another question: with that property I get an TypeError('Complex aggregates require an alias'). I think, I can fix this like that: `return self.item_set.aggregate(price=Coalesce(Sum('price'), Value(0)))['price']`. Can you confirm that? Finally a meta question: should I delete my comments as soon as they are cleared or does StackOverflow "punishes" that somehow (like it does for deleting questions)?

Comment: @RalfZosel: yes, you need to give it a proper name, so `.aggregate(price=...).`